# How to prevent outline marks on trousers?

Tags: clothing

Some of you may have noticed that if you have fairly tight trousers on - such as chinos - if you have anything in your pocket, such as a phone, ID card, or coins and such things, after a while outlines of the objects become visible on the outside of the trousers.
For me it mostly occurs if I rub against the object and apply pressure to outside of the material, then I find it becomes more prominent and happens more quickly than if just left in the pocket.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to prevent this from happening?

My trousers are quite new and I assume that this could somewhat amplify the effects as they have not yet been washed but it has happened on some of my older clothes as well which is getting a tad tiresome!

Comment: I find this only happens with my dark jeans. Blue jeans never seem to have this problem. I keep my phone in my jean pocket. I too am looking for a solution, though specifically for black jeans that somehow don't have this issue. It really only happens with my phone. The white outline will fade away by the morning usually. Since I want to invest in more of a certain brand of black jeans, I'll be experimenting with adding some thin inner fabric to my phone pocket. I'm looking for an explanation of why it's specifically a "white" mark coming from an object inside of the pocket.

Comment: Here's a decent explanation of what's happening with jeans and the dye: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-my-cellphone-leaving-an-imprint-on-my-new-dark-wash-jeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry your objects in a bag: your cellphone, wallet, keys and other things you used to carry in your pocket. There are many bags for woman or for man, you can look very modern carring such a bag or backpack. There are different sizes and you can choose if you want to carry many things or just keys, a cellphone and some money. There are bags for important documents which you can hide under your shirt. And I have seen a belt with zippers on the inner side for hiding small objects.

Otherwise you can put these objects in your jacket not in your trousers.

You can hang a key on your neck tied with a textile band like a necklace.

Put some money in your bra. Some girls keep there a mp3 player while walking.

Answer (score 1):

I no longer carry anything in any my pockets except one credit card, a driver license, and keys on a small ring if absolutely necessary. I made this change some time ago due to reasons expressed in the OP. I had a pocket knife, change, many keys, and a fat wallet. It's just what a person is accustomed to and these things are not missed. Also it saves pockets from coming apart inside. When I carry a phone I use a clip put on the front of my pants rather than the side.